How to change supervisor configuration in Github Actions
I want to add (replace) supervisor configuration and start command by Github Actions.
Log for ssh-actions:
======CMD======
cd $SSH_TARGET
tar -xvf artifacts.tar 
rm artifacts.tar
mv .env.staging .env
mv supervisor-chat-server.conf /etc/supervisor/conf.d
sudo supervisorctl reread
sudo supervisorctl update
sudo supervisorctl restart chat-server
======END======
out: .env.staging
out: chat_server
out: supervisor-chat-server.conf
err: sudo: a terminal is required to read the password; either use the -S option to read from standard input or configure an askpass helper
err: sudo: a password is required
err: sudo: a terminal is required to read the password; either use the -S option to read from standard input or configure an askpass helper
err: sudo: a password is required
err: sudo: a terminal is required to read the password; either use the -S option to read from standard input or configure an askpass helper
err: sudo: a password is required
2024/10/25 07:41:58 Process exited with status 1

Without sudo - error 'permission denied'.
So, how to change supervisor configuration by Github Actions?
UPDATE: SSH user belongs to sudoers on target host
